# Need to list all files in a directory on AIX

Tags: aix, readdir

Have a program that needs to list all the files in a directory on AIX.

Have successfully done this on Windows:-

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

 if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
   fprintf(stderr,"Can not scan for files.\n");
   goto MOD_EXIT;   
 }

 do
 {
   if (! (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
   {
     printf("File:%s\n",ffd.cFileName);
   }
 }
 while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

and on Linux:-

```
d = opendir(szDir);
if (!d)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Can not open directory '%s'.\n",szDir);
  goto MOD_EXIT;    
}

while(dir = readdir(d))
{
  if (dir->d_type != DT_DIR)
  {
    printf("File:%s\n",dir->d_name);
  }
}
closedir(d);
```

`readdir` appears to exist on AIX, but from the manual it would appear it only returns directories not files. The field `d_type` does not exist in the `dirent` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `readdir()` refers to *directory entries* it means *entries in the directory*, not subdirectories of the directory. So you can get all the names from there.

To discover if they are files or directories, the portable / reliable way is to to `stat()` the result. There are standard macros to test the `st_mode` returned in the stat buffer (e.g. `S_ISDIR`)

Comment: `stat()` appears to require a filename as a parameter. I wish to list all filenames. From the manual `readdir()` apparently only returns directory entries. How do I get the filenames to pass into `stat()`?

Comment: Actually, it returns _entries in the directory,_ not _entries in the directory that are directories themselves._

Comment: The readdir gets you the d_name field in the dirent. This part is portable.

Comment: Ah - that was the missing piece. Thank you @ZsigmondLőrinczy